# How can I run a sudo terminal command from applescript?

Tags: terminal, applescript, sudo

How can I run code "sudo ettercap -C" with sudo permissions in applescript?

```
display dialog "Start ettercap?" buttons {"Boot", "Cancel"}
do shell script "sudo ettercap -C"
```

This is for a project i'm doing. Dont ask :D

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `sudo` use `with administrator privileges`

```
display dialog "Start ettercap?" buttons {"Boot", "Cancel"}
do shell script "ettercap -C" with administrator privileges
```

See [Technical Note TN2065: do shell script in AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2065/_index.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Now its saying command "/bin/sh: ettercap: command not found" however it is a command as I can run it on terminal with no issue

Comment: Then try to pass the full path for example if ettercap is in `/usr/local/bin` : `do shell script "/usr/local/bin/ettercap -C"`